# Apache Cordova with ios8 InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, ios8

I'm using Cordova version 3.5.0 with XCode 6 beta 3 to test out the application with iOS8. However, none of the plugins (network connection status and inAppBrowser) are working.

If have already used:

```
if (navigator.userAgent === undefined) {
    navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function() {
        return("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit");
    });
}
```

Which is supposed to fix problems with iOS8.

Comment: I'm curious if you are still having issues with beta 5?  I'm seeing a lot of "Deprecated attempt to access property geolocation / navigator on a non-Navigator object."

Comment: I'm having problems too. The plugin's values are set in the config.xml, the javascript file is loaded. And if I call "window.open" InAppBrowser responds (console logged its JS), but nothing is happening on screen!

Comment: btw, using Xcode 6 beta 7.